# Returns a list of elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

in view:

```
<p><label class="btn btn-primary" role="button" onclick="Select(@item.ProductID)">select</label>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Select(PID) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/TopProducts/GetInfo",
            type: 'Get',
            data: { id:PID }
        }).done(function(result) {

            $("#p1").text(result[0]);


                    });

           };     


</script>
```

in controller:

```
        public string[] GetInfo(int id)
        {
            string[] find = new string[2];

            var test =
                db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == id).Select(s => new { s.ProductName, s.ProductImageName });

            find[0] = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == id).First().ProductName;
            find[1] = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == id).First().ProductPrice.ToString();

            return find;
        }
```

result:s
first of system.string[]
please help me to use Returns a list of elements in jquery
my problem : $("#p1").text(result[0]);
not work and show  system.string[]

Comment: There isn't much of a description of the nature of the problem or what it is you are asking for.

Comment: In order to 'help others help you', you should state what you expect to happen, what is actually happening - and any troubleshooting and/or research you've done to correct the problme prior to posting here.

Comment: I want when I click on an element of the database name and the product was put on a display element without refresh page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return `Array`, `IEnumerable` or any `Collection`, your Action should return `JsonResult`.

Change signature and return statement like below

```
    public ActionResult GetInfo(int id)
    {
        string[] find = new string[2];

        var test = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == id).Select(s => new { s.ProductName, s.ProductImageName });

        find[0] = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == id).First().ProductName;
        find[1] = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == id).First().ProductPrice.ToString();

        return Json(find, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In this case better way is

```
    public ActionResult GetInfo(int id)
    {

        var prduct = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == id);
        //Some business logic here

        return Json(prduct, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In AJAX `done` callback will get the JSON result

```
done(function (result) {
    //click F12 keyboard key and see Browser-console
    console.log(result);//{ProductID: 1, ProductName: "Product-1", ProductImageName: "P-Img.png", ProductPrice: 10}
    if (result) {//If result esists
        console.log(result.ProductID);//1
        console.log(result.ProductName);//"Product-1"
        console.log(result.ProductImageName);// "P-Img.png"
        console.log(result.ProductPrice);// 10
    }
});
```

Hope you understand!